# pandas, how to convert any columns which contain words into numbers (i,e, map them)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mapping

I have a dataframe, with columns such as company name, price, buy/sell, qty.  I want to convert any column containing a string into a numerical value. I.e. a mapping say buy=1, sell=2 etc. I would ideally like to create a function to do this.

I know i can use:

```
df['company_value'] = df['company_name'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
```

But how do i create a function to map any column containing a string/word to a mapping?

Comment: can we get a sample input and output data so we can replicate and solve this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: was triggered by the response of Josh Friedlander below. I like his angle, but he has the mapping the wrong way around. Using that idea:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['monday','tuesday','wednesday','monday','thursday','monday','friday','monday','saturday','sunday']),columns=['G'])

def mapDFcol(df,colName):

    map_dict = dict([[j,i] for i,j in enumerate(df.loc[:,colName].unique())])

    df[colName+'map'] = [map_dict[i] for i in df.loc[:,colName] ]


    return df



mapDFcol(df,'G')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using EddyG's sample data of

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['monday','tuesday','wednesday','monday','thursday','monday','friday','monday','saturday','sunday']),columns=['G'])
```

You could simply use

```
map_dict = dict(enumerate(df.G.unique()))
```

giving you

```
{0: 'monday',
 1: 'tuesday',
 2: 'wednesday',
 3: 'thursday',
 4: 'friday',
 5: 'saturday',
 6: 'sunday'}
```